# Remove friend class dependency in the following case

Tags: c++, friend, ooad

```
class foo
{
    bar b;

    someFunction()
    {
        b.alphaObj->someFunctionOfAlpha();
    }
};


class bar
{
    friend class foo;
    // many more friends

private:
    alpha *alphaObj;
};
```

How do I remove the friend dependency without exposing the private members with getters and setters.
I understand friend classes could help in enhancing encapsulation but there are a lot of friend classes defined in my class exposing the private members to all. Hence I am thinking of a better approach and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Requiring a lot of friends indicates a set of poorly encapsulated classes - Why do so many classes require access to class bar?

Comment: We are dealing with legacy code here and that's how it is. We are thinking of refactoring now with a better design

Comment: The example here feels a bit too generic to be useful. Generally `someFunctionOfAlpha` wants to be moved to some other class where it can be made public. It could potentially be a wrapper that say `bar` creates, or become a member of `bar` itself. Another option is to pass a callback function and call that, instead of calling whatever it is directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent of your `friend` issue, being required to write this

```
b.alphaObj->someFunctionOfAlpha();
```

is not the best design. You should rather call (*):

```
b.someFunctionOfAlpha();
```

Now it is also obvious how to remove the friends:

```
class bar
{
public:
    void someFunctionOfAlpha() { alphaObj->someFunctionOfAlpha(); }

private:
    alpha *alphaObj;
};
```

(*) This guideline has a name, I just cannot find it at the moment. In general, calling a method should be like: "Do that!". Calling a method should not be like "Show me your internals so I can do what I want".

Comment: Thank you. This answer shows a valid point but does not answer the question. Hence not marking as correct

Comment: @abhilashanand why does it not answer the question? I show you how you can resolve the need for `friend`

Comment: Yes. But this exposes the inner features of alpha class indirectly by making it public. I have mentioned it as a constraint to not expose the inner functionalities by means of getters and setters

Comment: We had a discussion and this was pretty good and hence marked as correct. Another suggestion was the make the member public and make it a const such that it cannot be modified. If there are a lot of variables then your suggestion could result in a lot of code. Thanks for your effort

Comment: I think you are referring to "Law of Demeter" above :)

Comment: @abhilashanand yes you mentioned no getters and setters and I tried to give some hint that getters and setters is not what makes OOD. Anyhow I am not using getters/setters. For alternatives and pros/cons you should have made the requirements more clear in the question. Yes indeed it is Demeters Law, will edit that in